# Using Xpath in Smarty to Parse RSS Feed

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, smarty

I have a PHP script that works quite well to parse an rss feed and build a web page with the information formatted just like I need. The simplified PHP script looks like this:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://myrrs.com');

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($xml->xpath('//item') as $item) { 
        printf('<li><a href="%s"><img src="%s" title="%s/></a></li>', 

        $item->myurlpath, $item->myimagepath, str_replace('.', ' ',$item->title) ); 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

But now I am trying to generate the same script functionality inside a Smarty template. Smarty does not recommend using {php}{/php} plus I tried and it did not work.

I know you can load the xml (first line in my PHP script like this:

```
    {$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://myrss.com')}
```

But I do not know how to replicate the functionality in Smarty syntax of the foreach(Xpath), and the printf part passing the extracted values.

I have seen sample foreach statements in Smarty, but nothing with Xpath functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: If you've found an answer, you should add it down below and then mark it as the answer so people know this question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the correct way:

```
{$rss=simplexml_load_file('http://myrss.com')}
{foreach $rss->channel->item as $a}

  <li><a href="{$a->myurlpath}"><img src="{$a->myimagepath}" title="{$a->title}"/></a></li>

{/foreach}
```

I hope this helps somebody....

Thank you.